# using enriching response payload from call mediator

Tags: wso2, orchestration, wso2-esb

I am calling a micro-service through my WSO2 ESB Config Language Call Mediator, 
I then pass the request to an enrich mediator to and then I log and use a respond mediator.

The issue I have is that the I can not even see the payload returned by the micro-service though my micro-service indicates that it was called and returned a response payload without any errors. Secondly my sequence throws an error when I run it. My error is below.

> JsonUtil #writeAsJson. Payload could not be written as JSON. MessageID: urn:uuid:fe8d8ec5-473e-43c0-bc98-22a7211e2d86
>   [2018-06-08 12:30:26,209] [] ERROR - JsonStreamFormatter Error occurred while writing to application/json
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Below is my sequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="balanceEnquirySeq" trace="disable"
 xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
 <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="data_request"
  scope="default" type="STRING" />
 <log level="custom">
  <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="in_request" />
 </log>
 <switch source="json-eval($.agentInstitutionCode)">
  <case regex="001">
   <payloadFactory media-type="json">
     <format>{


 "channel": "",
 "type": "",
 "customerId": $1,
 "customerIdType": "",
 "submissionTime": "",
 "reqTranId": $2,
 "passcode": ""

 }
</format>
<args>
 <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.agentAccountNumber" />
 <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.requestID" />
</args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <log level="custom">
    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="CHANGED_REQUEST" />
   </log>
   <property name="messageType" scope="default" type="STRING"
    value="application/json" />
     <call >
     <endpoint>
       <http method="post" uri-template="http://127.0.0.1:8080/stanbic/dobalenquiry" />
    </endpoint>
   </call>
  <enrich>
  <source type="body" clone="true" />
  <target type="property" action="child" property="org_type" />

   </enrich>
   <log level="full"/>
   <respond />
 </case>
</switch>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Based on the error my guess would be that that your payload is somehow not properly formatted. The moment you call the enrich (or perhaps the log) mediator WSO2 starts parsing the message and throws the error.

Comment: @Jan but when I use a send mediator it gives me my respond payload in xml

Comment: If you log the response from the microservice before you enrich it look correct. I want to make sure that everything is working as expected before the enrich mediator.

Comment: Another guess: you are not creating valid JSON? Try putting " around the $1 and $2. So "$1" instead of $1

Comment: @Jan same result the error is not from my json because if I use a send mediator it works perfectly and returns the correct xml payload.

Comment: I suspect we are talking about different things, cannot post any screenshots here so I'll try to explain in normal answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: If i put the payload in a JSON validator I get an error]

If I use a json validator and just put the content of your payloadFactory there then I get an error on line 3 and 7 if the property is empty.
Try:

```
 "channel": "",
 "type": "",
 "customerId": "$1",
 "customerIdType": "",
 "submissionTime": "",
 "reqTranId": "$2",
 "passcode": ""
```

To see if that helps.